# Is it possible to use selenium and requests at the same time?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, http-post, webautomation

I am thinking of creating a web automation using python, basically it will open browser using selenium webdriver proceeds to click on a few buttons, then using requests post method, fill up a form and then continue to use selenium again. So in short I am asking if we are able to use both selenium and python requests interchangeably?

Comment: ##yes why not ?

Comment: wanted to clarify, sorry if this question sounded dumb, I just started python few days ago

Comment: No issue, you can continue with selenium and requests.. it's pretty much interesting and easy to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can! I use both the libraries interchangeably in the same code file. It is very helpful.

For eg. First I use requests library to fetch the webpage, next I use Selenium whenever I have to change specific parameter in the webpage (like selecting a radio button, inserting form credentials, etc.), and then ***based on the complexity of the source code***, I either use BeautifulSoup, or I continue using Selenium!